# It seems like "-p" sizing longer works with tmux. Is there any workaround?

Tags: command-line, tmux

It seems like `-p` sizing longer works with tmux.

Before a recent update, the script had 4 panes; now, only see 3 panes. This line seems to have stopped working:

```
tmux split-window -p 27
```

The script use to have a right half, split 50/50 and left half split 73/27. The OS is Mac, latest. Installed with brew, version 3.4

Is there any workaround?

```sh
!/bin/sh
    
tmux new-session  -s "Local" -d
tmux send-keys "" C-m ;  
tmux split-window -h  
tmux send-keys "  " C-m
tmux split-window -v  
tmux send-keys " " C-m
 
tmux selectp -t 0  
tmux split-window -p 27  
tmux send-keys " "  
tmux -2 attach-session -d
```

Comment: I want 4 panes , I only see 3  "tmux split-window -p 27" stop working. Want right half , split 50/50 and  left half split 70/30..